# (Android+Retrofit 2) - Is there a drawback on the usage of Static Headers with Interceptors?

Tags: java, android, header, retrofit, interceptor

Let's say I have 5 API endpoints and 4 of them require the `@Header "Authorization"`; the other one doesn't.

Is there a drawback or anything of the sort when I use an Interceptor to insert the header for all API calls even though one of the endpoints does not require it? :)

Comment: It seems more like server-side problem. Ask them to standardize all endpoints, at least for `auth`. ;)

Comment: @StasLelyuk Yeah, we'd love to ask them :( but circumstances with our back-end guys prevent us from having a standardized batch of endpoints. Now, we client devs deal with this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Probably would be better use a more customizable approach that's `retrofit2` provides - dynamic headers. A dynamic header is passed like a parameter to the method. The provided parameter value gets mapped by Retrofit before executing the request. Example:

```
@GET("/yourEndpoint")  
Call<List<Obj>> getSomth(@Header("Your-Header") String yourHeader);
```

But if you only worrying about extra header passing, I don't see any drawback in your particular case.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sir! ^_^
Yeah, I've come across Dynamic Retrofit Headers before and used them. My co-devs just find it too repetitive to do when so many of our endpoints require that header that's why we're gearing towards the usage of Static Headers.

I just posted this question here to make sure that there are no drawbacks (or if they are negligible, if there are some).

Thanks again, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    Request request = chain.request();
    if (!request.url().toString().contains("/tapi/login/login")) {
        String cookie = SharedObj.getCookie();
        builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
    }
    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
}
```

This is my solution.All api need cookie except login api('/tapi/login/login') ,So I judge url to decide to wether to add cookie in request.

Comment: Um.. Sir, I'm looking for answers about any kind of disadvantage (a possible security leak, or a slowing down of process, or any kind of drawback) with regards to the usage of static Headers on Interceptors..

Thank you for your response though. :)

Comment: Um.....Sorry,I did't understand your meaning at first.If you add header in api which need 'auth' header you don't need a static header.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem using Interceptor with header for all API.

Set headers in interceptors and use to all API. If the API method is with or without auth it will be worked.

Like this - Create ones, use everywhere.

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
        //Add headers here using requestbuilder.
        String authToken =//Your Authtoken 
        if (authToken != null)
            requestBuilder.header("Authorization", authToken);
        requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body());
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    });
```

In Retrofit

```
   Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("baseUrl").client(httpClient.build()).build();
```